# Print to network connected printer android

Tags: android, printing, bonjour

I have tried many ways to print to network connected printer. Basically i want to print to the printer which is LAN connected. With default NSD manager we cannot detect it. But i was able to get service by

```
  compile 'com.github.andriydruk:rxdnssd:0.9.10'
```

But main issue is with socket connection. Most of times it is throwing IOException and some case whole PJL commands run but printer isn't executing it. Can anybody share some code or sample project to print to those printers?

```
sendTPrinter() {
        DataOutputStream outToServer = null;
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        String result;
        InputStream fileInputStream=null;
        try {

        clientSocket = new Socket(ipAddress, portNumber);
        InputStream inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        outToServer = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));

        char ESC = 0x1b;// "0x1b";
        String UEL = ESC + "%-12345X";
        String ESC_SEQ = ESC + "%-12345";
        outToServer.write(convertTOUtf(UEL+"@PJL COMMENT *Start Job*"));
        outToServer.write(convertTOUtf("@PJL \r\n"));
        outToServer.write(convertTOUtf("@PJL JOB NAME = $myjob"));
        outToServer.write(convertTOUtf("@PJL SET RET = "));
        //outToServer.writeChars(("@PJL SET PAPER=" + "A4"));
        outToServer.write((convertTOUtf("@PJL SET COPIES= 1")));
        outToServer.write(convertTOUtf("@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE = PCL"));
        outToServer.write(convertTOUtf(ESC+"E"));
        outToServer.write(convertTOUtf(ESC+"EHello World"));

        outToServer.write(convertTOUtf(ESC_SEQ));
        outToServer.write(convertTOUtf("@PJL \r\n"));
        outToServer.write(convertTOUtf("@PJL RESET \r\n"));
        outToServer.write(convertTOUtf("@PJL EOJ NAME = $myjob"));
        outToServer.write(convertTOUtf(UEL));

        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
        int count = bufferedInputStream.available();
        Logr.d("count "+count);
        result = SUCCESSFULLY_SENT;
    } catch (ConnectException connectException){
        Log.e(TAG, connectException.toString());
        result = connectException.toString();
    } catch (UnknownHostException unknownHostException) {
        Log.e(TAG, unknownHostException.toString());
        result = unknownHostException.toString();
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        Log.e(TAG, ioException.toString());
        result = ioException.toString();
    } finally{
        try {
           /* if (clientSocket!=null)clientSocket.close();

            if (outToServer!=null){
                outToServer.close();
           }*/
            if (fileInputStream!=null){
                fileInputStream.close();
            }
        }catch (IOException ioException){
            result = ioException.toString();
        }
    }
    return result;
}`
```

Comment: Have you considered using ipp printing instead?

Comment: @Nonos what if printer doesn't support ipp? I want to make sure each printer works.

Comment: Most modern printers support ipp unless you're looking at specific printers that don't

Comment: @Nonos can you please share some code snippet with ipp without using android native preview, where i can write bytes myself?

Comment: You can try this library: https://github.com/HPInc/jipp